# What exactly does GCC -fobjc-direct-dispatch option do?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, compiler-flags

The GCC manual says:

> ```
> -fobjc-direct-dispatch
> ```
>
> Allow fast jumps to the message dispatcher. On
> Darwin this is accomplished via the comm page.

Can I assume this flag eliminates dynamic dispatch? How does it work?
I believe it should be as fast as a C function call if it is linked directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the dynamic dispatch is still there (calls still route through `objc_msgSend`). And this option doesn't introduce any difference currently with x86(-64).

From http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-3.3/gcc/Objective_002dC-Dialect-Options.html:

> For some functions (such as `objc_msgSend`) called very frequently by Objective-C programs, special entry points exist in high memory that may be jumped to directly (e.g., via the "`bla`" instruction on the PowerPC) for improved performance. The `fobjc-direct-dispatch` option will cause such jumps to be generated. This option is only available in conjunction with the NeXT runtime; furthermore, programs built with the `-fobjc-direct-dispatch` option will only run on Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger) or later systems.

Comment: Sadly that documentation link is now broken; I'm not sure an equivalent document still exists!

Comment: Thanks to @earltedly there's a little more info at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21257633/28768 too