# What does GCC_FAST_OBJC_DISPATCH "Accelerated Objective-C Dispatch" actually do (or used to do)?

Tags: objective-c

For years I have seen this in Xcode's build settings list but never gotten round to researching what it does. Today I tried to do so and found Google is highly lacking in any info on the topic. Can any Objective-C veterans (I'm guessing of the late PPC era) shed any light on what this setting does (or did do)?

Comment: Cheers @MartinR; trust me to forget to search by the other name of the setting. Weirdly it seems I can only vote to close my question as a dupe too; not outright close it!

Comment: Happy to assist. ;) I was going to bring this up as a feature suggestion on meta, because this demonstrates how in some cases deleting one's own question isn't the best course of action (it's useful have the question here for people who search by this name), but it seemed to make sense to allow the OP to mark his own question as a dupe without cramming it into the overloaded Close Votes queue (108k and growing...). However, apparently the idea has already been discussed and rejected: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-askers-to-close-their-own-questions-unilaterally

Answer (score 3):

There's a Greg Parker reply here:

> Accelerated Objective-C dispatch on PPC is faster because it avoids the dyld stub (which is otherwise used for all cross-library calls). On i386 the dyld stub is much faster than the ppc equivalent, so we didn’t bother doing extra work to bypass it.

https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations.html#comment-63429be30b1123e8a78b7b37bbeb10fe